# What packages are required to make tasksel work on Xenial

Tags: lamp, tasksel

I have a Xenial (upgraded from Trusty) 64 bit Desktop install. I've installed the tasksel package in order to install a LAMP server (required for ZoneMinder). When runing "sudo tasksel", it displays the various package groups, some (e.g. Ubuntu Desktop) being marked with a * to show that they are already installed. LAMP server is not marked with a *. So I move the red marker to the [ ] position opposite LAMP server. However, pressing the Enter or Return keys just exits tasksel. I've tried the * and x keys with no success: they do nothing. Am I missing some packages that tasksel requires?

Comment: I've just tried a number of keys. Typing t causes a * to appear against LAMP server when the red marker is against it. It then installs the appropriate packages when the Tab key is pressed to move the "cursor" to Ok and pressing the Enter key then causes the installation of the appropriate packages.

Comment: karel, you're correct about answer being in the question to which you referred. Typing space also works.